# python3 sending files via socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

everything should be alright,
but received file is always being damaged
the data is matched without any difference
remove the hash tag
from print(data) if you want to see binary and compering by yourself
....................................................................
....................................................................

## server.py

```
import socket, threading, os
from time import sleep


host, port = '127.0.0.1', 442


class transfer :
    mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    def __init__(self):
        self.mysocket.bind((host, port))
        print(' Server is ready ..')
        self.mysocket.listen(5)
        conn, addr = self.mysocket.accept()

        file_name = 'test.webm'
        size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
        print(' file size : {}'.format(str(size)))

        send_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.send_file, args=(file_name, size, conn, addr, ))
        send_thread.start()

    def send_file(self, file_name, size, conn, addr):
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as file:
            data = file.read(1024)
            conn.send(data)
            while data != bytes(''.encode()):
                #print(data)
                data = file.read(1024)
                conn.send(data)

            print(' File sent successfully.')


Transfer = transfer()
```

## client.py

```
import socket, sys, threading

from time import sleep

host, port = '127.0.0.1', 442


class recv_data :
    mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    mysocket.connect((host, port))

    def __init__(self):
        data = self.mysocket.recv(1024)
        f = open('newfile.webm', 'wb')
        while data != bytes(''.encode()):
            #print(data)
            data = self.mysocket.recv(1024)
            f.write(data)


re = recv_data()
```

Comment: I would replace the `while data != bytes(''.encode()):` with `while len(data) > 0:`

Comment: nice edit 
but i need to solve the problem

Comment: Just `while data:` works as well.

Comment: `socket.send` does not guarantee all bytes are sent.  You have to check the return value.  You can also try `.sendall()`.

Comment: so many ways to limit the loop but its not the problem 
sendall() didn't do much

Comment: My assumption was that you're trying to send binary data but relying on the default character encoding to let you know when to stop reading and writing which may be problematic. If it were me, I would simplify server.py to not use threading just to see if everything works as you expect without threading. There's a socket programming HOWTO in the python docs that might also be helpful.

Comment: i saw HOWTO topics and they working with python 2 encode and decode in python3 caused problems 
anyway it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the client here:

```
def __init__(self):
    data = self.mysocket.recv(1024)
    f = open('newfile.webm', 'wb')
    while data != bytes(''.encode()):
        #print(data)
        data = self.mysocket.recv(1024)
        f.write(data)
```

the program never writes the result of the first `recv` into the file.  That data is thrown away and replaced by the result of the second `recv`, which becomes the first data written into the file.

To fix, move the `f.write` above the second `recv` call.

Comment: what a logic ^_^ 
i didn't notice that , its working now 
thanx alot