# Could not deserialize key data error after transferring public key file to server using the crpytography module

Tags: python, sockets, cryptography, valueerror

I'm trying to create a simple messenger in python with encryption using the cryptography module.

I searched how i could transfer a file [and i found this script here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812854/python3-sending-files-via-socket), which i modified for my needs.

I got the modified server, i got the modified client, but when i transfer the public key to the server and try to exctract the public key out of the file, it gives me this error (this is btw just my three files to test the transfering):

````
  File "X:/file_transfer_testing/server.py", line 28, in <module>
    public_client_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\file_transfer_testing\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\base.py", line 20, in load_pem_public_key
    return backend.load_pem_public_key(data)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\file_transfer_testing\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 1124, in load_pem_public_key
    self._handle_key_loading_error()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\file_transfer_testing\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 1382, in _handle_key_loading_error
    raise ValueError("Could not deserialize key data.")
ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.```
````

Here is the client file:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import file_transfer_client


host, port = 'fe80::c14:9eeb:7e9d:b459%4', 442
ADDR = (host, port)


private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        public_exponent=65537,
        key_size=2048,
        backend=default_backend()
    )

public_key = private_key.public_key()

pem = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)

with open('public_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pem)

transfer = file_transfer_client.transfer()
```

And the file_transfer_client file:

```
import socket
import threading

host, port = 'fe80::c14:9eeb:7e9d:b459%4', 442
ADDR = (host, port)


class transfer:
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(ADDR)

    def __init__(self):
        file_name = 'public_key.pem'
        send_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.send_file, args=[file_name])
        send_thread.start()

    def send_file(self, file_name,):
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as file:
            data = file.read(1024)
            self.client.send(data)
            while data != bytes(''.encode()):
                # print(data)
                data = file.read(1024)
                self.client.send(data)
            print('File sent successfully.')
```

This is the server file:

```
import socket
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization


host, port = '0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000', 442
ADDR = (host, port)


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

server.listen()

conn, addr = server.accept()

data = conn.recv(1024)
f = open('public_key_recv.pem', 'wb')
while data != bytes(''.encode()):
    f.write(data)
    data = conn.recv(1024)

with open('public_key_recv.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
    public_client_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
        key_file.read(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )
```

Which produces the error shown above while trying to get the publickey.

Am i missing something obvious on why this can't work?

Comment: `bytes(''.encode())` is an extremely painful way of generating an empty bytes object. Just use `b''` instead. Also, public key files are small, a read loop is overkill. Just read all the bytes in and send them over in one call: `self.client.sendall(file.read())`.

Comment: In the server, there is no point to writing the bytes out to a file only to read them in again. Just save the data as you are reading it in and then supply it to the serialization method.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! The `client.sendall(file.read())` really made the difference.